# Rails form is giving undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, rails-routing

This seems like such an easy question, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I have the following form code:

In the controller:

```
class ProjectApplicationsController < ApplicationController
    def new_project
        @project.new
        @referral = Referral.new
    end
end
```

In the view:

```
<%= form_for @referral do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :referrer_email %>
<% end %>
```

Routes File:

```
resources :referalls, only: [:create]
```

I have done this countless times before, the only difference being that the view the form is rendered from is different from the controller it is going to(the form should go to referrals#create).  For some reason I get the error:

```
undefined method `referrals_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fba5a11b4a0>:0x007fba5a119a10>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this error because ***there is no referrals_path. You have double l in referalls***

```
resources :referalls, only: [:create]
```

but it should be

```
resources :referrals, only: [:create]
```

Comment: Yes.  you have a typo.  Also, from the console you can type 'rake routes' to see what resources you have made available.

Comment: I can't believe I was this stupid.  Thanks Mandeep. I'll mark it correct when the timer lets me in 7 minutes.

Comment: @Philip7899 no issues. It happens :)

Comment: @mandeep You also have typo in your answer it should be `resources :referrals, only: [:create]` Not `resources :referals, only: [:create]`

Comment: @NitinVerma Yeah my bad, didn't see that. Thanks!